# Is there any way to change the frequency or the voltage in Gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to modify the frequency or the voltage in Gem5 to save power.

How I can change them in Gem5?

Comment: Also ask on mailing list. I haven't learnt power yet, it's something I want to do at some point. Related question at: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg18103.html Have you checked if the values are not just present in simobjects by looking into config.ini?